# AspNet Core 2.0 custom authentication scheme with no authentication

Tags: asp.net-core

We have a custom authentication handler implemented in ASP.NET core 2.0.
We would like to be able to make specific action methods which do not have authentication.

[AllowAnonymous] Doesn't seem to be working. When I put that attribute it is ignored. The authentication handler is still invoked.

Should we make a new kind of attribute ([NoAuthentication] and check this in the authentication handler. And how do we have to do this?

```
[Route("api/init"), HttpPost, IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Init([FromBody]BarInitRequest request)
{
       ...
```

Comment: Can you show us the controller code where the attribute is being ignored?

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: Thanks. Does the controller class definition have any attributes?

Comment: No. The custom scheme with authentication is active for all action methods and controllers. It is also the default scheme. So there is no [Authenticate] attribute.

Comment: This is just how *authentication* works - The middleware will authenticate each request (which is why it's middleware). What problem is this causing?

Comment: Well we need one web api action method request without authentication.

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing authentication and authorization. `[AllowAnonymous]`, `[Authorize]` et al are not intended to en/disable authentication. Your authentication handler is being asked to authenticate the user, but does not participate in deciding whether or not the user is authorized for a request. If you really do want to disable *authentication*, your handler will need to manage that itself.

Comment: So what should I do? I just have one authentication scheme with a handler setup. But I want to skip this for one specific api call.

Comment: Well, you have the custom attribute-based approach you suggested in your OP, or perhaps you could have a property on your authentication handler's options class (assuming this exists) that specifies a path, regex, whatever that it should match against the incoming request when deciding whether or not to proceed with whatever logic you have.

Comment: Ok and should i return AuthenticateResult.NoResult() in this case it doesn't participate in authentication?

Comment: If we would want to use a custom attribute: How can we check a custom attribute within the authentication handler? Controller context information is not available in the authentication handler.